# Render component with concat helper

Tags: javascript, ember.js, htmlbars

Is there a way to render component in HTMLBars as argument passed in concat helper?
I have `fa-icon` ember component and my custom component that displays label. I need to display it like:

```
{{my-simple-button label=(concat (fa-icon "pencil") " " (t "myAwesomeTranslate"))}}
```

but, obviously, `fa-icon` is a component not a helper.

**Update.**
Thanks! In fact I use `ember-async-button` with custom messages, and therefore I have to write something like

```
{{#async-button as |component state|}}
  {{#if state.isPending}}
    {{if pendingLabel pendingLabel (t 'site.actions.pending')}}
  {{else if state.isDefault}}
    {{label}}
  {{else if state.isRejected}}
    {{label}}
  {{else if state.isFulfilled}}
    {{label}}
  {{/if}}
{{/async-button}}
```

So I want a wrapper like `my-simple-button` which takes `label` and `pendingLabel` and hides those `ifs`. So I can't use block because I need to set up icons in 4 places. The only option I see is using ifs for `icon` and `pendingIcon` properties, but that makes code ugly. So basicly I want to know if there is a way to simplify this...

Comment: You need to give more context here, fa-icon component code js/hbs. Do you think calling/rendering component will return some data ?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, that's not really possible. Even if it is in some obscure way, passing a pre-rendered component just seems hacky.

The proper approach for this is to have a `{{yield}}` as part of your label which is a built-in mechanism in Ember to render components from external scope.

```
// inside templates/components/my-simple-button.hbs
{{yield}} {{label}}
```

Then you can just pass `fa-icon` as a child of `my-simple-button`:

```
{{#my-simple-button label="myAwesomeTranslate"}}
  {{fa-icon "pencil"}}
{{/my-simple-button}}
```

And it would render `{{fa-icon "pencil"}}` instead of `{{yield}}`.

If you want `my-simple-button` to specifically support icons, you could include an `icon` property and use `fa-icon` instead of `yield`:

```
// inside templates/components/my-simple-button.hbs
{{#if icon}}{{fa-icon icon}}{{/if}} {{label}}
```

And pass it like:

```
{{my-simple-button label="myAwesomeTranslate" icon="pencil"}}
```

Comment: I've just working to prepare a twiddle. [Here it is](https://ember-twiddle.com/e1451688f5505cae37f97c471f854b51). Completely the same ideas with you!